# Silverstripe 3 Config Condition

Tags: php, config, silverstripe

I am struggeling within the YAML configuration API, which docs can be found [here](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/configuration/configuration/). My use case:

I have a class with 2 "config" properties

```
class Foo extends Object {
  private static $host = null;
  private static $port = null;
}
```

Now I need per environment different host-names, but the same port.
Assuming, when in dev Environment the $host should be 1.1.1.1 and in live environment ist has to be 2.2.2.2. The port should be set to 10000;

All other sections should be valid for all env types

`config.yml`(does not work):

```
---
Name: myexcitingconfig
---
Only:
  environment: 'dev'
---
Foo:
  host: '1.1.1.1'
  port: 10000
---
Only:
  environment: 'live'
---
Foo:
  host: '2.2.2.2'
  port: 10000
---
Bar:
  test: 'hooray'
```

In this example, all properties of "Foo" are null, only "Bar::test" is set.

```
Debug::dump(Config::inst()->get('Foo', 'host')); // => null
Debug::dump(Config::inst()->get('Foo', 'port')); // => null
Debug::dump(Config::inst()->get('Bar', 'test')); // => 'hooray'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your class namespaced?

Comment: @bummzack: no, it is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way your YAML File is structured, that your actual config instructions get misinterpreted as YAML document "headers" and your environment based rules get interpreted as config. Have you tried something like this?

```
---
Name: myexcitingconfig
---
# Global config here
Bar:
  test: 'hooray'

---
Only:
  environment: 'dev'
---
Foo:
  host: '1.1.1.1'
  port: 10000
---
Only:
  environment: 'live'
---
Foo:
  host: '2.2.2.2'
  port: 10000
---
```

Also, when using namespaced classes, you should write the fully qualified classname in your YAML file. So if `Foo` is in the namespace `My\Awesome\Module`, your config entries would be:

```
My\Awesome\Module\Foo:
  host: '2.2.2.2'
  port: 10000
```

Comment: Yes ! It seems, that no config settings are parsed after an "only" condition.
The following works, but not the last "test2" property:
`
---
Name: myexcitingconfig
---
Bar:
  test: 'hooray'
---
Only:
  environment: 'dev'
---
Foo:
  host: '1.1.1.1'
  port: 10000
---
Only:
  environment: 'live'
---
Foo:
  host: '2.2.2.2'
  port: 10000
---
Bar:
  test2: 'hooray, also'
`

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! It seems, that no config settings are parsed after an "only" condition.
The following works, but not the last "test2" property:

```
---
Name: myexcitingconfig
---
Bar:
  test: 'hooray'
---
Only:
  environment: 'dev'
---
Foo:
  host: '1.1.1.1'
  port: 10000
---
Only:
  environment: 'live'
---
Foo:
  host: '2.2.2.2'
  port: 10000
---
Bar:
  test2: 'hooray, also'
```

Comment: I think your assessment is wrong. Config settings should be parsed after an "only" condition, but you can't "reconfigure" the same object twice in one yaml file. If you have `Bar` on top, and `Baz` at the bottom, I'm pretty confident that it's going to pick up `Baz` as well…